# Issues Deploying Next.js 13 Project on Vercel with Dynamic Routes not fetching the required data on the Server Side

Tags: next.js, react-redux, server-side-rendering, dynamic-routing, app-route

I am facing challenges deploying my Next.js 13 project on Vercel. The major hiccups seem to be around the `blog/[id]` dynamic route and the Server Side not fetchiing some data. Here's a summarized breakdown:

**Vercel CLI Version**: Using Vercel CLI 31.4.0.

. **Runtime Issues**:

- Errors fetching users with the message "Failed to fetch users".
- Errors fetching posts with the message "Document does not exist".
- TypeError on accessing properties of undefined in `blog/[id]/page.js`.

git rep [https://github.com/matteo-dirollo/matteo-dirollo-next/blob/main/src/app/(public)/blog/page.jsx]

I would appreciate insights and potential fixes for these issues. Thanks in advance!

I tried to console log the data on the /blog/[id] page and it works.

Comment: Can you share more details on the errors you are getting?